# Android Studio simple methods aren't recognized

Tags: android, android-studio

Simple methods like Intent, startActivity @Override etc... Won't work, it just shows a redline under them and even after I created a totally new project it shows redline under them. This picture is a picture of a new project created seconds ago (didn't copy paste code so you could see the redline) -

[image]

Comment: Change the gradle.properties file and change the heap size as per your requirement. After that, Invalidate your android studio caches and Restart.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the only solution but I just reinstalled Android Studio and it is now working fine. Something must've probably got deleted somehow and the reinstall made it work again.